# Run an awk statement from a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sunos

I want to run this awk statement from inside a shell script:

```
awk -F, '$45==341 && $47==341 && ($13==3) && $15 <=600 && $48==5410 && $50=="pattern"' \
full_path/logfile.log | cut -d, -f15 | sort -unr |head -1
```

If I run it directly from command line, it works perfectly but from inside a shell script it fails.

I understand there's an issue with shell script command line parameters and awk references, like `$45`, `$47` and so on...

I tryed to escape `$` without success.

Comment: @Cyrus great Edition! Thanks. in fact i'm using the full path to file. I think the issue is not there.

Comment: It's working fine for me. Can you include the appropriate snippet from your shell script?

Comment: BTW Are your tags correct? Linux and Solaris?

Comment: In what way does it "fail"?

Comment: ah, Linux and Solaris. The default `/bin/awk` in Solaris is really (really!) old and missing a lot of features. Either use `/bin/nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`. Good luck.

Comment: You understand wrong - there are no issues with shell script command line parameters and awk references, like $45, $47 and so on...

Comment: I am a bit concerned by `$50=="pattern"`. If the "pattern" really is a pattern, you should probably be using "~" rather than "==".

Comment: @MarkSetchell is right and we should never use the word "pattern" anyway as it's so ambiguous. Use the words "string" or "regexp" or "condition" (`$N~/regexp/{<action>}` or `$N=="string"{action>}` or `<condition>{<action>}`. The guys who invented awk got it wrong in the documentation when they talked about "pattern"s instead of "condition"s and we're suffering the lingering effects of that with all this "pattern" nonsense.